# Long Bluetooth Discovery and Scanning issues in Android Fragment

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth, android-adapter, tablet

**Goal:** Build a fragment page that discovers the names and addresses of Bluetooth devices within range and displays them in a ListView from which user can select a device to connect to. It is something similar to the Bluetooth scanning process in the local device.

**Problems encountered:**

1. Sometimes, scanning process runs for a very long time (> 5mins) and 
   does not stop
2. Sometimes, discovery process is fast and is able to output "No devices found" or output names and addresses of devices found accordingly
3. Sometimes, Bluetooth devices within range does not appear in the ListView although there were Bluetooth devices discovered in the local Bluetooth setting. However, when I switch to the local Bluetooth setting and switch back to my app, the ListView starts displaying exactly the Bluetooth devices listed in the local Bluetooth setting.

I've been spending weeks trying to solve these problems but to no avail. Appreciate any kind souls that can point out my mistakes?

**Pictures:**

[Long scanning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK697.jpg)

[My app's Listview got updated after switching back from Local Bluetooth setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRukr.jpg)

Here's my **code:**

```
     import android.app.Activity; 
     import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
     import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
     import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.content.IntentFilter;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.ViewGroup;

     import android.widget.AdapterView;
     import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.widget.CompoundButton;
     import android.widget.ListView;
     import android.widget.ProgressBar;
     import android.widget.Switch;
     import android.widget.TextView;
     import android.widget.Toast;

     import java.util.Set;


    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     */
    public class Server_fragment extends Fragment {


    // Component fields
    Switch bluetoothSwitch;
    TextView titlePairedDevices;
    ListView pairedListView;
    TextView titleNewDevices;
    ListView newDevicesListView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    // Member fields
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;

    public Server_fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_server_fragment, container, false);

        // Initialize the switch to perform Bluetooth on/off
        bluetoothSwitch = (Switch) v.findViewById(R.id.bluetoothSwitch);
        titlePairedDevices = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices);
        pairedListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
        titleNewDevices = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_new_devices);
        newDevicesListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        // Initialize array adapters.
        // One for already paired devices and
        // one for newly discovered devices
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.device_name);
        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.device_name);

        // Find and set up the ListView for paired devices
        pairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
        pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        // Find and set up the ListView for newly discovered devices
        newDevicesListView.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
        newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Get local Bluetooth Adapter
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        /**
         *  If the switch is off initially,
         *  This method enables Bluetooth when user presses switch
         *  If the switch is on initially,
         *  This method disables Bluetooth when user presses switch
         */
        bluetoothSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    bluetoothSupportCheck();
                    titlePairedDevices.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    displayPairedList();
                    titleNewDevices.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    doDiscovery();
                } else {
                    bluetoothSupportCheck();
                    titlePairedDevices.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    displayPairedList();
                    titleNewDevices.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    newDevicesListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        // Set switch mode according to local Bluetooth status
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            bluetoothSwitch.setChecked(true);
            titlePairedDevices.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            displayPairedList();
            titleNewDevices.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            doDiscovery();
            makeDiscoverable();
        } else {
            bluetoothSwitch.setChecked(false);
            titlePairedDevices.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            titleNewDevices.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newDevicesListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Make sure we're not doing discovery anymore
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Unregister broadcast listeners
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }


    /**
     *  This method checks whether Bluetooth is supported
     *  If yes, ask user for permission to allow Bluetooth to be on
     */
    private void bluetoothSupportCheck() {

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No bluetooth device available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            bluetoothSwitch.setChecked(false);
        } else if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() && bluetoothSwitch.isChecked()) {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ADAPTER DISABLED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    makeDiscoverable();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bluetooth was not enabled. Exiting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    bluetoothSwitch.setChecked(false);
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void makeDiscoverable() {

        if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
            Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
            startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        }
    }


    /**
     *   Display the list of paired devices
     */
    private void displayPairedList() {

        // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
        // Display the list of paired Bluetooth devices
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            getView().findViewById(R.id.paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        } else {
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.clear();
            if ( bluetoothSwitch.isChecked() ) {
                String noDevices = "\t No device has been paired".toString();
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            }
            else {
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.clear();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     *  The on-click listener for all devices in the ListViews
     */
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {

            // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
            String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            // Finish this Activity
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    };


    /**
     *  The BroadcastReceiver that listens for discovered devices and
     *  changes the title when discovery is finished
     */
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }

                // When discovery is finished
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                titleNewDevices.setText("Other Available Devices");

                // If no new devices found
                if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {

                    if ( bluetoothSwitch.isChecked() ) {
                        String noDevices = "\t No device found".toString();
                        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                    } else {
                        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.clear();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!bluetoothSwitch.isChecked()) {
                        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.clear();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    };


    private void doDiscovery() {

        titleNewDevices.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        titleNewDevices.setText("Scanning for devices...");

        // If we're already discovering, stop it
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    }


}
```

Comment: On which devices are you testing on and which devices trying to connect to?

Comment: I'm testing on the device Lenovo Yoga Tab 3 Pro. I'm trying to connect to Windows PC.
Right now the problem is I'm having trouble trying to even discover Android devices.